# Eigenvalues of vectors with irrational entries

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have been trying to find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix: $\begin{bmatrix}3 & -2\\1 & -1\end{bmatrix}$. So far I have got $\lambda_1=1+\sqrt2$ and $\lambda_2=1-\sqrt2$. I am stuck at finding eigenvectors at this point. Regular row-reduction method gives me hard to compute values. I am sure I am missing something obvious here.

Comment: What weird answers?

Comment: Care to share your "weird answers" so that people can help you understand what's wrong (if there is in fact anything wrong)?

Comment: Let me rephrase that: hard to compute. For instance if I reduce R1C1 to 1 then I get irrational entry in R1C2, and if I were to reduce R1C2 then I lose 1 in R1C1. It's kind of cyclical annoyance.

Comment: @parzival You want to reduce R2C1 to 0 first.  Probably easiest to start by switching the rows.

Comment: Why do you need row reduction? There's only one equation to deal with.

Comment: @alex care to elaborate?

Comment: The matrices $A-\lambda_i$ have rank $1$, so you can take whichever of the two rows you like better.

Comment: For instance the first row of $A-\lambda_1I$ is $(2-\sqrt 2,-2)$, whence you get the eigenvector $$\pmatrix{2\\2-\sqrt 2}$$

Comment: that helped. Thanks @alex

Comment: No worries. You're welcome. (Sorry for being verbose, it has to be at least 15 characters...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've gotten the eigenvalues correctly. Now, given a matrix $A$ with an eigenvalue $\lambda$, an eigenvector for $\lambda$ is just a non-zero element of the null space of $A-\lambda I$.

So, let's find the null space of $$\begin{bmatrix}3 \strut& -2\\1 & -1\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}1+\sqrt{2} & 0\\0 & 1+\sqrt{2}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2-\sqrt{2} & -2\\1 & -2-\sqrt{2}\end{bmatrix}$$
We row-reduce to simplify the matrix while keeping its null space the same:
$$\begin{bmatrix}2-\sqrt{2} & -2\\1 & -2-\sqrt{2}\end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow{\;\;\Large\mathsf{\text{row 2} \;-\; \left(\frac{1}{2-\sqrt{2}}\right)\,\text{row 1}}\;\;}\begin{bmatrix}2-\sqrt{2}\strut & -2\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
Obviously, for a non-zero vector $\Bigl[\begin{smallmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{smallmatrix}\Bigr]$, we have that

$$\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}2-\sqrt{2} & -2\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\strut\\x_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}&\iff (2-\sqrt{2})x_1+(-2)x_2=0\\\\\\
&\iff x_2=\frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{2}x_1
\end{align*}$$
and an easy choice of $x_1$ and $x_2$ that satisfy this is $x_1=2$ and $x_2=2-\sqrt{2}$.

Let's check that this worked:
$$\begin{bmatrix}3 \strut& -2\\1 & -1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2\strut\\2-\sqrt{2}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}3\cdot 2+(-2)\cdot(2-\sqrt{2})\strut\\1\cdot 2+(-1)\cdot(2-\sqrt{2})\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2+2\sqrt{2}\\2\sqrt{2}\end{bmatrix}=(1+\sqrt{2})\begin{bmatrix}2\strut\\2-\sqrt{2}\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\checkmark$$
I leave it to you to do this process for the eigenvalue $1-\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you're curious how to get the row reduction method to work:

$\begin{bmatrix}3-\lambda & -2 \\1 & -1-\lambda\end{bmatrix} \sim \begin{bmatrix}1 & -1-\lambda\\3-\lambda & -2 \end{bmatrix} \sim \begin{bmatrix}1 & -1-\lambda\\0 & -2+(-1-\lambda)(-3+\lambda) \end{bmatrix}$.

This looks messy, but, as alex says, this matrix must be rank 1.  So $-2+(-1-\lambda)(-3+\lambda) = 2-(1-\lambda)^2=0$ when you write it all out.  Thus, the eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ are exactly the multiples of $\begin{bmatrix}1+\lambda\\1\end{bmatrix}$ (note that we switched the rows once, so we have to switch them back).

This actually tells you the eigenvalues as well, since they are just the two roots of the equation $2-(1-\lambda)^2=0$.

Of course alex's approach is much better than this.  I include it mostly to make the point that the row reduction method *will* always work, if done correctly.  This is worthwhile practice to ensure that your toolbox is functioning correctly.