# Eigenvectors with Irrational elements

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

After searching through SE, I found this question ([Eigenvalues of vectors with irrational entries](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695340/eigenvalues-of-vectors-with-irrational-entries)). 
This is exactly what I am asking, with a different matrix and different eigenvalues.  The problem is I'm not really sure how the solution presented here works?  The step where it says $$\xrightarrow{\;\;\Large\mathsf{\text{row 2} \;-\; \left(\frac{1}{2-\sqrt{2}}\right)\,\text{row 1}}\;\;}$$ does not seem to work. At least I don't see how it works, in terms of the basic arithmetic

Anyways, this is the matrix I have:
$$\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1\\3 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

and these are the eigenvalues I got:
$\lambda_1=\frac{3}{2}-\sqrt{13}$ and $\lambda_2=\frac{3}{2}+\sqrt{13}$

Answer (score 0):

For $\lambda_1$, after you subtract, you want to solve the system

$$\begin{bmatrix} 3/2+\sqrt{13} & 1 \\ 3 & 1/2+\sqrt{13} \end{bmatrix} x = 0.$$

A nice shortcut in the $2 \times 2$ case is to realize that if your eigenvalue is correct then these two equations are redundant. So if we use the first one, we have

$$(3/2+\sqrt{13})x_1+x_2=0.$$

I don't want to divide by that ugly number, so I won't: I'll choose $x_1=1$ and then $x_2=-(3/2+\sqrt{13})$. So an eigenvector is $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -(3/2+\sqrt{13}) \end{bmatrix}$.

You can do the same for $\lambda_2$.

In higher dimensions this starts to get ugly, because you have to actually do some row reduction to find an eigenvector.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This is what I needed to see.  I am still not sure how the division works, but I will likely be using this technique from now on.